# Sequelize destroy from multiple tables

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I would like to delete records from multiple table one after another. Under a single router, how could I call the following destroy functions one after another

```
function deleteFromTable1(param1, transaction) {
  return table1_model.destroy({
    where: { param1 },
    transaction
  });
}

function deleteFromTable2(param1, transaction) {
  return table2_model.destroy({
    where: { param1 },
    transaction
  });
}

function deleteFromTable3(param1, transaction) {
  return table2_model.destroy({
    where: { param1 },
    transaction
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say

> Under a single router

I am assuming you have a setup similar to a `Node.js` and `Express.js` application where your route and handler look like the following:

```js
app.post('/delete', function (req, res) {
  // delete some items from database
})
```

In this case, you could do the following:

```js
function deleteItems(req, res) {
  // since Sequelize `destroy` calls return promises, 
  // you can just wrap all of them in `Promise.all`
  // and "wait" for all of them to `resolve` (complete)

  const handleSuccessfulDeletion = () => {
    res.status(200).json({ 
      status: 200, 
      message: 'OK' 
    })
  }
  const handleError = (error) => {
    // ...
  }

  Promise.all([
    deleteFromTable1(param1, transaction),
    deleteFromTable2(param1, transaction),
    deleteFromTable3(param1, transaction)
  ])
    .then(handleSuccessfulDeletion)
    .catch(handleError)
}
app.post('/delete', deleteItems)
```

This way, all deletion calls get completed before you return the `success` response.

---

Alternatively, if you need to your call need to be sequential, then you could do the following:

```js
function deleteItems(req, res) {
  const handleSuccessfulDeletion = () => {
    // ...
  }
  const handleError = (error) => {
    // ...
  }

  deleteFromTable1(param1, transaction)
    .then(() => deleteFromTable2(param1, transaction))
    .then(() => deleteFromTable3(param1, transaction))
    .then(handleSuccessfulDeletion)
    .catch(handleError)
}
app.post('/delete', deleteItems)
```

Here's an example - [jsbin.com](https://jsbin.com/pisenafaqo/edit?js,console)

Comment: I've already tried with the promise. I my senario there is some dependencies between the tables. so I need to execute it sequentially

Comment: What about the second approach? I've edited my answer